# Generic methods evaluation type - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Below is the playground code snippet

```
import UIKit

class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
}

class SubCell: BaseCell {
    
}

var type: BaseCell.Type = SubCell.self


extension UICollectionViewCell {
    @objc public class var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

func registerNib<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) -> String {
    return T.reuseIdentifier
}

print(type.reuseIdentifier) // prints "SubCell"

print(registerNib(type)) // prints "BaseCell" **how?**
```

When I'm using the generic function here the output changes, why? Anything im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Generics are evaluated at compile-time, not runtime. The type of `type` is `BaseCell.Type`, so that's what will be used for the call to `registerNib`. Its value is not relevant, just its type.

You didn't mean a generic here. You meant to pass the type *value* so it could be evaluated at runtime:

```
func registerNib(_ type: UICollectionViewCell.Type) -> String {
    type.reuseIdentifier
}
```

Comment: Is this part and parcel of the fact that generics are not covariant with respect to their parameterized type?

Comment: @matt Very true and important, but I don't believe this matters in this case. The issue is that `T` is determined at compile-time based on type (not value) information, so it doesn't matter that `SubCell.self` is what is being passed. All that matters is that the type of `type` is `BaseCell.Type`. There's no covariance attempted.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I always get a bit confused about this myself.